# How to embed verbatim in pspicture?

Tags: pstricks, verbatim, fancyvrb, pst-barcode

I'm trying to insert a QR code at the beginning of my thesis with the contents being the BibTeX entry for it.

Any way of embedding the raw text in `\psbarcode`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{minimal}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)
    \psbarcode{
      \begin{verbatim} % won't work
@MastersThesis{,
  author = {J\'ulio ...},
  title = {...},
  year = {...},
  ...
}
      \end{verbatim}
    }{}{qrcode}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It seems the [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package provides a `BVerbatim` environment for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you want verbatim anyway as you also need to take care of PostScript quoting such as `\\` for `\`.

[image]

which an online decoder says is

```
Raw text    @MastersThesis{, author = {J\'ulio ...}, title = {...}, year = {...}, ... }
Raw bytes   44 d2 04 04 d6 17 37 46 57 27 35 46 86 57 36 97 37 b2 c2 06 17 57 46 86 f7 22 03 d2 07 b4 a5 c2 77 56 c6 96 f2 02 e2 e2 e7 d2 c2 07 46 97 46 c6 52 03 d2 07 b2 e2 e2 e7 d2 c2 07 96 56 17 22 03 d2 07 b2 e2 e2 e7 d2 c2 02 e2 e2 e2 07 d2 00 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec
Barcode format  QR_CODE
Parsed Result Type  TEXT
Parsed Result   @MastersThesis{, author = {J\'ulio ...}, title = {...}, year = {...}, ... }
```

tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{minimal}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)
    \psbarcode{
@MastersThesis{,
  author = {J\string\\'ulio ...},
  title = {...},
  year = {...},
  ...
}
    }{}{qrcode}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

For newlines this works:

```
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)
    \psbarcode{\string\n
@MastersThesis{,\string\n
  author = {J\string\\'ulio ...},\string\n
  title = {...},\string\n
  year = {...},\string\n
  ...\string\n
}
    }{}{qrcode}
  \end{pspicture}
```

Comment: Are you saying it's better to escape control characters manually? The other problem i see is line breaking, when i read the generated QR code, it's one line.

Comment: `better` might be the wrong word, I'm saying that I didn't know of another way (and since Herbert also manually quoted characters, and he knows this a lot better than me I guess that's right.) `\string\n` might work for newline I'll try...

Comment: @juliohm yes confirmed by decoding that `\string\n` works to put a newline in the QR string

Answer (score 1):

use the optional argument `parse` and decimal values for the characters:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)
    \psbarcode{%
@MastersThesis^123,author=^123J^250lio ...^125,title=^123...^125,year=^123...^125,...^125}{parse}{qrcode}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

`^123` decimal ASCII for `{`, 
`^125` for `}`, and `^250` for `ú`

[image]

Comment: Inserting ASCII code isn't a great solution. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: it is not possible to use the reserved PostScript characters without coding them as `^xyz`